# Entity Framework many-to-many intersect

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, many-to-many

I have a many-to-many relation and I need help on how to get this result

```
public class Customer {
    public virtual IList<CustomerPreference> CustomerPreference { get; set; }
}

public class Preference {
    public virtual ICollection<CustomerPreference> CustomerPreferece { get; set; }
    public int DefaultValue { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerPreference {
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual Preference {get; set; }
}
```

Lets say I have a Customer1 and Pref1, Pref2, Pref3 with default values of 0. 
If I insert a CustomerPreference record for Pref1 with value 1, I would like to query this result

Customer  | Preference | Value
Customer1 | Pref1      | 1
Customer1 | Pref2      | 0
Customer1 | Pref3      | 0

Thanks.

Comment: Your tables aren't `ICollections`, even though it's supposed to be a many to many relationship?

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is done through simple select from `CustomerPreference`, make sure you include `Customer` and `Preference` is selection result.

```
var query = from item in context.CustomerPreference
                  .Include(cp=>cp.Customer)
                  .Include(cp=>cp.Preference)
            select new {item.Customer, item.Preference, item.Value};
var result = query.ToList();
```

Comment: The entity or complex type cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: First you should fix your code because your properties are not having names `public virtual CustomerPreference`